# Globalization 1.x with DevExtreme library

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, devextreme, javascript-globalize

I have a question with the DevExtreme v.16.1 in combination with Globalize 1.x. They upgraded from 0.x to 1.x and I cannot make it work since the update.

I put the loading of the librries in an external file, and loaded the rest of the application after the promise is resolved.

This is tje importatn part of my localize.js

```
$(function () {
    MK.localisation.init = $.when(
        // CLDR libraries for NL-nl
        $.getJSON("js/localization/nl/ca-gregorian.json"),
        $.getJSON("js/localization/nl/numbers.json"),
        $.getJSON("js/localization/nl/currencies.json"),

        // CLDR libraries for DE-de
        $.getJSON("js/localization/de/ca-gregorian.json"),
        $.getJSON("js/localization/de/numbers.json"),
        $.getJSON("js/localization/de/currencies.json"),

        // CLDR libraries for EN-uk
        $.getJSON("js/localization/en/ca-gregorian.json"),
        $.getJSON("js/localization/en/numbers.json"),
        $.getJSON("js/localization/en/currencies.json"),

        //additional CLDR libraries
        $.getJSON("js/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json"),
        $.getJSON("js/cldr/supplemental/timeData.json"),
        $.getJSON("js/cldr/supplemental/weekData.json"),
        $.getJSON("js/cldr/supplemental/currencyData.json"),
        $.getJSON("js/cldr/supplemental/numberingSystems.json")
    ).then(function () {
        // Normalize $.get results, we only need the JSON, not the request statuses.
        return [].slice.apply(arguments, [0]).map(function (result) {
            return result[0];
        });
    }).then(
        Globalize.load
    ).then(function () {
        return $.when(
            $.getJSON("js/localization/nl/dx.all.nl.json"),
            $.getJSON("js/localization/nl/localization.nl.json"),
            $.getJSON("js/localization/de/dx.all.de.json"),
            $.getJSON("js/localization/de/localization.de.json"),
            $.getJSON("js/localization/en/dx.all.en.json"),
            $.getJSON("js/localization/en/localization.en.json")
        ).done(function (r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6) {
            Globalize.loadMessages(r1[0]);
            Globalize.loadMessages(r2[0]);
            Globalize.loadMessages(r3[0]);
            Globalize.loadMessages(r4[0]);
            Globalize.loadMessages(r5[0]);
            Globalize.loadMessages(r6[0]);
            Globalize.locale("nl");
            $.each(MK.config.navigation, function () {
                if (this.title.indexOf('@') === 0) {
                    this.title = Globalize.formatMessage(this.title.substring(1));
                }
            });           
        });
    });
```

If i put a breakpoint at Globalize.locale("nl"), I see that all messages are loaded inside the Globalize object.

I call this function at the top of my index.js the following way:

```
$(function () {

    //setup localisation
    MK.localisation.init.done(function () {
        Globalize.locale("de");
        //rest of the app decalration follows here
    })
```

I can also use the translation within JavaScript without problem

```
Globalize.formatMessage("someString")
```

However, the DevExtreme modules are not translated. They remain in english. It is also possible to let strings be translated directly inside the view with the @someString syntax. This does not work with strings i declared either. It does work with the build in strings though, so the parsing does work.

I suspect timing problems, maybe the views are parsed before the strings are loaded? Cannot solve the problem though, followed the manual of devextreme to the point i think...

http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/SPA_Framework/Localization/?version=16_1&approach=Knockout

Comment: I've found the similar question here https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T397683 Could you check it out?

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately they suggest using version 16.1.5, which is the Version I am using. But I will try update to 16.1.6 which was released today, and check again

Comment: Unfortunately the update had no effect whatsoever. Any other ideas anybody?